# Chi Squared Analysis on Data sets that don't have matching frequencies

Tags: python, statistics

I have 15 data sets each of which I have fitted with a curve. Now I am trying to determine the quality of fit by doing a chi-squared test; however, when I run my code:

```
chi, p_value = stats.chisquare(n, y)
```

where `n` is the actual data and `y` is the predicted data, I get the error

> For each axis slice, the sum of the observed frequencies must agree with the sum of the expected frequencies to a relative tolerance of 1e-08, but the percent differences are:
> 0.1350785306607008

I can't seem to understand why they have to add up to the same total - are there any ways I can run a chi-squared test without muddling my data?

Answer (score 1):

This chi-squared test for goodness of fit indeed requires the sums of both inputs to be (almost) the same. So, if you want to check whether your model fits the observations `n` well, you have to adjust the counts `y` of your model as described e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Goodness_of_fit). This could be done with a small wrapper:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
import numpy as np

def cs(n, y):
    return chisquare(n, np.sum(n)/np.sum(y) * y)
```

Another possibility would be to go for R and use [`chisq.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/chisq.test).